# Need a windows Nmap line for "# awk '/open/{print $2}' hostdiscovery.gnmap > livehosts.txt"

Tags: linux, windows, port, nmap, port-scanning

I need to do this step after first scanning ports, I have a `hostdiscovery.gnmap` file after that and this is my next step:

```
awk '/open/{print $2}' hostdiscovery.gnmap > livehosts.txt
```

but this is a Linux command line and I'm using windows for this project I need to do on my PC... do you know how I can get the similar windows command?

This is my source on step 2: https://www.networkstraining.com/nmap-commands-cheat-sheet/

Comment: You can install awk on Windows. msys2, cygwin, git bash, etc. etc. etc. Or maybe look for a powershell-based equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

With Powershell:

```
ForEach ( $lin in Get-Content hostdiscovery.gnmap ) { if ($lin -like "*open*") { $wrds=$lin.Split(" "); Write-Output $wrds[1] } } >> livehosts.txt
```

Read the file hostdiscovery.gnmap line by line and then if the line contains "open", split the line into the array wrds and print the first index (the second word)

Comment: It is not working. I tried it in powershell, is there a misspelled word in your command line? Sry for your frustation. Im very new to this, I have to get this project done in a week.